# how to convert Firebase progress count Units to percent

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on an iOS app where you can upload pictures, I am using this method to track my **Uploading progress**:

```
    uploading.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) in
        if let completedUnitConter = snapshot.progress?.completedUnitCount {
           self.navigationItem.title = String(completedUnitConter) 
        }
    }
```

it tracks the progression well but the units(Snapshot) it returns is like this 32, 485, 4758, 594747... and so on until the image gets uploaded to Firebase.

I want to convert these units into percentage(0% - 100%) so the user understands what is going on after they press the upload button, so I was wondering if any of you could show me how to do this?

any help from you guys would be greatly appreciated!!

UPDATE:

```
    uploading.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) in

        let percentComplete = 100 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
         / Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)

        let percentageConverted = String(format: "%.0f", percentComplete)

        self.navigationItem.title = String("\(percentageConverted)%")

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The progress object also contains a `totalUnitCount` that you can use to find the percentage,

```
let percentComplete = 100.0 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
/ Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)
```